# Intellij IDEA - Export all keybindings in Intellij to allow me to edit them in a file rather than in the preferences

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When you create a new keymap in Intellij it is always based on other keymap. It kind of extends it and only the changes are recorded.

Example file:

> mykeymap.xml

```
<keymap version="1" name="momomo-keymap" parent="Default for XWin">
  <action id="$Redo">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift alt back_space" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl y" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateDebugToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt 5" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl 9" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateProjectToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt 1" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl 1" />
  </action>
  <action id="Back">
    <mouse-shortcut keystroke="button4" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl alt page_up" />
  </action>
  ...
</keymap>
```

This is kind of nice because then I can edit them manually quicker, and I can make simple changes between Mac and Linux versions (for instance Command key vs CTRL key)

Is there a way to **get a dump of all the shortcuts** used and not used in a file in the format above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found it in:

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps

Not sure if it is complete though. Will have to test and try.

Comment: Nope, not complete, but provided  a somewhat of a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Under the installation directory of IntelliJ IDEA, navigate to `lib\resources.jar`. Extract it, and then find `keymaps` directory, which includes all keymap files such as `Default for XWin.xml`.

Comment: i think those starts empty no? they are only filled with changes. what i wanted was to get the original ones that are set, and then manually modify them rather than through the dialog. I think the accepted answer did that back then albeit i stopped using that after changing computer.

Comment: Maybe you have all of it though ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that's an old thread, but I have faced the same question and come up with the simple plugin, it just exports entire keymap to IntelliJ XML format: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18927-keymap-xml-exporter

Comment: Cool! Will it export even non configured ones, allowing us to configure them? Does it read them back upon edit?

Comment: It exports any Keymap it can find custom, default, and even those which are invisible in the Keymap editor (like Windows keymap on MacOs).  Exported XML contains the complete set of shortcuts.

Comment: The plugin has no import functionality, but I've managed to get a keymap from manually updated XML, by replacing the content of custom keymaps, which IDE stores in `c:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\jba_config\win.keymaps\Windows copy.xml` and `c:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\keymaps` on Windows and in `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/keymaps/` on MacOS. Its seems hacky but it works. (I have not learned yet the possibility to import a keymap from XML via the plugin)

Comment: Cool, yes, i remember that if you edit the actual keymap it will actually update immediately but unsure where you exported ones go, if they overwrite the original ones without comprimising them, then that could work!